# Hibernate errors in named queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, pojo, named-query

I am trying to pull information from a table where the current date is between the first and last day of any given month.

I am getting a runtime error "Errors in named queries: Department.byDate"

I am providing you with what code I think could be causing the problem, if any additional code is needed please let me know in a comment.

My named query which looks like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Department.byDate", query="select * from department where date >= :first AND date <= :last")
```

I am using this named query in my DAO in a method which looks like this:

```
public List<Department> getRecords(Date dateFirst, Date dateLast){
    Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Department.byDate");
    query.setDate("first", dateFirst);
    query.setDate("last", dateLast);

    List<Department> depList = (List<Department>)query.list();

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    return depList;
}
```

My method of getting that first and last days of the months looks like this:

```
Calendar first = Calendar.getInstance();
first.set(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH), Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Date dateFirst = first.getTime();

Calendar last = Calendar.getInstance();
first.set(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH), Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Date dateLast = last.getTime();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In HQL/JPQL you are working with entities and their properties, thus `*` character has no meaning.
2. HQL/JPQL class and property names are [case sensitive](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2524).

You should write your query the following way:

```
select d from Department d where d.date >= :first AND d.date <= :last
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew * wasn't meant to be used in HQL it was there from my last edit of various attempts at getting it to work. That solved this problem.